# Unable to init new firebase project from console

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I'm trying to host my webapp on firebase and am currently running into this issue:

**My order of operations:**

```
(in root) > npm install -g firebase-tools
> firebase login
> $ npm run build
> cd dist
> firebase init iq18
> (select my desired app in FB dropdown)
> returns: Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

No matter what I try, after running init from my /dist directory, I can not get it to actually deploy to firebase. Full error from the logs:

```
[info] 
=== Project Setup
[info] 
[info] First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
[info] You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
[info] but for now we'll just set up a default project.
[info] 
[debug] [2018-06-04T19:03:39.456Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects  

 Mon Jun 04 2018 15:03:39 GMT-0400 (EDT)
[debug] [2018-06-04T19:03:39.812Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 
=== Iq17 Setup
[debug] [2018-06-04T19:03:42.715Z] TypeError: features[nextFeature] is not a function
    at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/init/index.js:13:49)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/init/index.js:14:14
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

**Things I've tried:**

1. Deleted my /dist directory and rebuilt the app
2. Logged out of firebase and relogged in
3. Deleted the placeholder app from firebase account

Not quite sure what else I can do to fix this deploy issue.

Comment: Run any failing Firebase CLI commands with `--debug` to get more details error output.  You may also need to contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @DougStevenson I ran `--debug` and got the full error from the logs as mentioned above

Comment: If you are in a rush.. try to downgrade your firebase-tools

Comment: Now, examining those error logs, is there anything you find helpful to act on?  If not, contact support and provide them the detailed information.

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake tried to drop the version to 3.18.0 instead of 3.18.5, but doesn't seem to do anything. Waiting to hear back from support I guess.

Thanks!